# Google Chrome app name changed after installing LINE from Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, icons

After a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04, I decided to install Google Chrome (via `apt-get install google-chrome-stable`) and install LINE Messenger from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/menkifleemblimdogmoihpfopnplikde?hl=en). When I started LINE, the icon shows up as the Chrome icon instead of the LINE icon. After closing Chrome, the Chrome browser shows up as "LINE" instead of "Google Chrome" in Applications, and searching for "Chrome" gives "LINE" with the Chrome icon.

So far I have tried to purge and reinstall the Chrome app, uninstalling the LINE app, changing names, to which none has worked. Starting the Chrome app from `usr/share/applications` launches 2 separate apps on the launcher, the proper "Chrome" app, which closes after a few seconds, and the "LINE" named chrome app, which stays open and shows the Chrome window.

I have just used Ubuntu for a week, so I don't know what to do.

[image: Applications]
[image: Launcher]

Answer (score 1):

I would try locating the LINE or Chrome `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` and renaming it to Google Chrome. Also, open the `.desktop` file with a text editor and change the name to Google Chrome

Comment: I've tried to rename it, and it still doesn't work. Also, the LINE App is within Google Chrome.

Comment: @nugie and did you try opening the `.desktop` file with a text editor and changing the line that says `Name=` to Google Chrome?

Comment: Yes, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

i already solve this issue, well technically, i cant find the .desktop file, so maybe this another idea in my mind will work and yeah it worked. so heres my idea, go to **/usr/share/applications/** then find the chrome, unlock the chrome app from your launcher of lets say the LINE name on your launcher, then the open folder of /applications, drag the chrome icon to your launcher and thats it, The name of the app changed back to the original name. Hope you get it.