# Installed Google Chrome and it was installed with a wrong name

Tags: google-chrome, launcher

I just uninstalled chrome version 55 because I noticed it wasn't automatically updated with `apt-get update/dist-update`.

I tried installing the current version of chrome in two ways:

1. Downloading the .deb file from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html and just double clicking on it.
2. Following this instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/510186/718495

In both ways Chrome got installed, but the name was incorrect:

[image: Wrong name]

Then I followed the instructions given here [Google Chrome app name changed after installing LINE from Chrome Web Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851048/google-chrome-app-name-changed-after-installing-line-from-chrome-web-store) with no successful results. The `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` file doesn't even contain the word "Feedback".

I tried locking this file directly to the launcher, but when I open it another  icon named 'Feedback' appears. It's very annoying, what can I do?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Perhaps you need to delete the profile rather than reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if what I did was deleting the profile, but thanks to you I found the issue.

I found that in `.local/share/applications` there was another `google-chrome.desktop` file that had  this line `Name=Feedback`. I deleted the file and it's all back to normal.

Comment: That is the correct way to fix it. Please add this as the answer (you can answer your own questions).